# Can't get state with react-router. (maybe not working react-redux connect())

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

```
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    return {
        userData: state.userData
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Init);
```

connected component like this.
btw when I read this.props, it doesn't have userData.
`this.props` is like below
http://prntscr.com/iypnvj

---

update with detail

route file

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import {Layout} from "../components/layout/Layout";
import {Dashboard} from '../components/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import {User} from '../components/User/User';
import {UserEdit} from '../components/User/Edit';
import {Role} from '../components/Role/Role';
import {RoleEdit} from '../components/Role/Edit';
import {Register} from '../components/Register/Register';
import {Init} from '../components/Init/Init';

export default (store) => {
    return (
        <Route>
            <Route component={Layout}>
                <Route path="/" component={Init} />
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path="/user" component={User} />
                <Route path="/user/create" component={UserEdit} />
                <Route path="/user/edit/:id" component={UserEdit} />            
                <Route path="/role" component={Role} />
                <Route path="/role/create" component={RoleEdit} />
                <Route path="/role/edit/:id" component={RoleEdit} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Route>
    )
}
```

layout file

```
import * as React from "react";
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { update_user_data } from '../../actions';
export class Layout extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar />
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    return {
        userData: state.userData
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{
    return bindActionCreators({
        update_user_data: update_user_data
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Layout);
```

Navbar file

```
import * as React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import {
    Collapse,
    Navbar,
    NavbarToggler,
    NavbarBrand,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    NavLink,
} from 'reactstrap';
import {User} from '../../models/user';
import Avatar from 'react-avatar';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { update_user_data } from '../../actions';

export class NavBar extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false,
            // user: new User()
        };
        axios.get('/api/users/me').then(resp=>{
            // this.setState({ user: resp.data[0] });
            this.props.update_user_data(resp.data[0])
        })
    }
    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }
    logout(){
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'api/users/logout',
            baseURL: '/'
        })
        .then(resp => {
            window.location.pathname = '/home'
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar light expand="md" style={navbarStyle} fixed="top">
                    <NavbarBrand href="/">xxxxxxx</NavbarBrand>
                    <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                        <span className="child_center_div">Hi, {this.props.userData.name}</span>
                        <div style={{margin: '0px 10px 0px'}}>
                            {
                                this.props.userData.avatar?
                                <Avatar round={true} size={40} src={"/api/avatar/"+this.props.userData.avatar} />
                                :
                                <Avatar round={true} size={40} name={this.props.userData.name} />
                            }
                        </div>
                        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
                    </div>
                    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                        <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink  onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>Logout</NavLink >
                            </NavItem>
                        </Nav>
                    </Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const navbarStyle={
    boxShadow: '0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',
    background: 'white'
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    return {
        userData: state.userData
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{
    return bindActionCreators({
        update_user_data: update_user_data
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavBar);
```

in navbar, I can get store http://prntscr.com/izpcfv
but in layout, same problem http://prntscr.com/izpcne

Answer (score 0):

With no other details, I think it would more be related to react-redux than react-router. The way you try to display the state, from where or the error you have may be helpful.

If you decide to check your state in your `<Init />` component, you could write something like this:

```
import store from './store.js';

const Init = (props) => {
  console.log(store.getState());
  return (
    //your JSX
   )
}
```

Also, be sure to have your routes inside `<Provider store={store}></Provider>`. Only the components rendered by the routes inside `<Provider></Provider>` can be connected to redux store.

Feel free to add some details if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have to use react-redux. I updated detail so would you take a look again?

Comment: You need to create a store first like "const store = createStore(yourReducer)" and then use this store in the Provider tag that should encapsulate all your routes. Without this, you can't access redux store. (Don't forget to import createStore from react-redux package.